# No check box for .jar files in properties for running files as executable

Tags: 14.04

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 and every time I try to run a .jar file I go to properties > permissions but there is no check box to make the file executable? I'm using Openjdk 6. I Have not seen any other questions similar to this.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit more I want to say that I just want to mark it as executable to run it.

Comment: Does the jar file have a main() entry point?  You can 'mark' any file as executable using `chmod +x filename` from a terminal shell.  However setting the executable bit is not a sufficient condition to make a file execute.

Answer (score 1):

Open up a command line/terminal and run `chmod a+x filepath/file.jar`